# Is this a reference copy or a shallow copy?

Tags: reference, copy, stringbuffer

What is the difference of a reference copy and a shallow copy? How do you populate a StringBuffer Array? And is this code correct, in respect to creating a reference copy?

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ArrayRefCopy {
    public static int n = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuffer[] hel = new StringBuffer[n];

        refCopy(hel);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hel));


    }

    public static StringBuffer[] refCopy(StringBuffer[] bra){

        StringBuffer[] ber = new StringBuffer[n];
        return ber = bra;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, practically, your method `refCopy()` doesn't do anything at all.

You pass a reference to your array `hel` into the method `refCopy()` when you execute it, which will be available there as `bra`. Inside the method, you create a new array and assign a reference to the new array to `ber`. Right in the next line, you overwrite this reference again, however, with the reference to your array `hel` which you received by the method parameter `bra`.

You then return the reference to array `hel`, you don't use the returned value however.

As a consequence, `hel` still holds a reference to the same array as before and the new array you created inside `refCopy()` falls out of scope and will be garbage collected.

**Regarding the meaning and definition** of *reference copy* and *shallow copy*, please google the terms. It should be pretty easy to find a comprehensive definition/explanation.

Comment: This "answer," is far from helpful.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry if I annoyed you with my presence.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ArrayRefCopy {
    public static int n = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuffer[] hel = new StringBuffer[n];

        refCopy(hel);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hel));


    }

    public static StringBuffer[] refCopy(StringBuffer[] bra){

        StringBuffer[] ber = new StringBuffer[n];
        return ber = Arrays.copyOf(bra, n);
    }
}
```